# Graphical output suddenly quits working with allegro based header

Tags: c++, graphics, visual-studio-2013, allegro5

EDIT: ANSWERED. Upon examination of the g.drawLines in my drawBackground function, I was drawing a point, not a line. It was user error.

Our school has written a header that simplifies much of allegro 5. I'm writing a program that will use that header (GameEngineV4) to simply emulate checkers, however, I'm having some difficulty getting the board to display to the screen.
Here is my code:

```
#include "GameEngineV4.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void drawBackground(GameEngineV4, const int, const int);

int main()
{
    const int BOARD_WIDTH = 600;
    const int BOARD_MARGIN = 100;
    GameEngineV4 g;                 // instantiate graphic object

    g.initializePanel(800,800);         // initialize Window
    g.setBackground(g.CYAN);                // color the background

    drawBackground(g, BOARD_MARGIN, BOARD_WIDTH);

    //* cleanup
    g.displayPanel();

    system("Pause");
    g.displayDelay(1.0);                // wait 10 seconds
    g.closePanel();
    return 0;
}

void drawBackground(GameEngineV4 g, const int BOARD_MARGIN, const int BOARD_WIDTH){
    g.setColor(g.BLACK);
    int i = 0;
    int offset = (BOARD_WIDTH / 8) * i; //Variable to hold the amount a line should be shifted from original.
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        offset = (BOARD_WIDTH / 8) * i;
        g.drawLine(BOARD_MARGIN, BOARD_MARGIN + offset, BOARD_MARGIN, BOARD_MARGIN + offset); //Horizontal lines
        g.drawLine(BOARD_MARGIN + offset, BOARD_MARGIN, BOARD_MARGIN + offset, BOARD_MARGIN); //Vertical lines
    }
}
```

The difficulty lies somewhere in the drawBackground function. I had tested the drawBackground function first by replacing the drawLine code in the for loop with `g.drawLine(50, 50 + offset, 450, 450 + offset);` and the code displayed just fine then. Why would changing it to calculate using constants affect my code?

Coded and compiled in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7.

EDIT: Of course, it would be a bit simpler if I included the header and implementation for GameEngineV4

Here's GameEngineV4.h:

```
#ifndef _GameEngineV4
#define _GameEngineV4
#include <string>
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>                //Our primitive header file
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>
using namespace std;
class GameEngineV4
{
private:
    int gSleep;
    int gSpeed;
    bool appRunning;
    ALLEGRO_COLOR colortable[32];
    ALLEGRO_FONT * fonttable[32];
    int keyTable[256];
    int default_pen;
    int default_brush;
    int default_font;
    int default_BGColor;
    double default_thickness;
    bool keyPressed;
    int pressedChar;
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *gdisplay;
public:
    GameEngineV4();
    //-------------------------------------------------
    // Game Engine Functions
    //-------------------------------------------------
    // call to return last key pressed
    int  gameLastkey();
    // call to set game speed;
    void gameSetGameSpeed(int);
    void gameSetSpeed(int);
    // call to set game speed;
    int gameGetGameSpeed();
    int gameGetSpeed();
    // call to set display delay;
    void gameSetDisplayDelay(int);
    // start game
    int gameEngineMain(void);
    // call to repaint window
    void gameRepaint();
    // creates and fills a rectangle color is index into standard color table
    void fill_rect(int xl,int yl,int xr,int yr,int penColor,int brushColor);
    void fill_rect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h);
    // creates and fills an ellipse
    void fill_ellipse(int x1 ,int y ,int w,int h,int penColor,int brushColor);
    void fill_ellipse(int x1,int y1,int w,int h);
    // text out string, x, y, color code
    void text_out(char *,int ,int ,int);
    void text_out(char *txt, int x,int y);
    void text_out(LPCSTR txt,int x,int y,int clr);
    void text_out(LPCSTR txt,int x,int y);

    // draw line from point1(x1,y1) to point2(x2,y2)
    void draw_line(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2); // uses default color
    void draw_line(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int color);
    // draws ellipse
    void draw_ellipse(int x1,int y1,int w,int h,int penColor,int brushColor);
    void draw_ellipse(int x1,int y1,int w,int h); // uses default color
    // draws rectangle
    void draw_rect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h,int penColor,int brushColor);
    void draw_rect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h);
    // sets default color
    void color(int pen,int brush);
    // sets default pen color
    void pen_color(int pen);
    // sets default brush 
    void brush_color(int brush);
    // register call backs
    void registerGameMain(void (*fun)());
    void registerGameInit(void (*fun)());
    void registerGameQuit(void (*fun)());
    void registerGamePaint(void (*fun)());
    void registerGameKeyUp(void (*fun)(int));
    void registerGameKeyDown(void (*fun)(int));
    void registerGameLMouse(void (*fun)(int,int,int));
    void registerGameRMouse(void (*fun)(int,int,int));
    void registerGameMoveMouse(void (*fun)(int,int,int));

    void playBeep1();
    void playBeep2();
    void playBeep(float g, float s );
    void playWav(char * filename, float gain, float speed, float duration);
    void playWave(string filename, float gain, float speed, float duration);
    int initializeAudio(int samples);

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // call back functions
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // called during initialization
    void gameInit();
    // called during initialization
    void gameMain();
    // called at exit
    void gameQuit();
    // called to repaint screen
    void gamePaint();
    // keyboard and mouse functions
    void gameKeyUp(int);
    void gameKeyDown(int);
    void gameLMouse(int,int,int);
    void gameRMouse(int,int,int);
    void gameMoveMouse(int,int,int);

    // initialization methods
    void initColorTable();
    void initFontTable();
    void initKeyTable();
    void GoPaint();

    // Alternate Graphics functions
    int initializePanel(int width, int height);
    int initializePanel(int width, int height, int color);
    void closePanel();
    void displayPanel();
    void displayDelay(double delay);
    void setBackground(int color);
    void setBackground(int r, int g, int b);
    void setThickness(double t);
    void setPenColor(int pen);
    void setColor(int pen);
    void setColor(int r, int g, int b);
    void setBrushColor(int brush);
    void setBrushColor(int r, int g, int b);
    void setFont(int font);
    void setFontSize(int fontSize, int flag);
    void setFont(string family, int fontSize, int flag);
    void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    void drawOval(int x1,int y1,int w,int h);
    void drawRect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h);
    void drawString(char *txt,int x,int y);
    void drawString(string txt,int x,int y);
    void drawARC(int x1,int y1,int r, int w,int h,float st, float dt);
    void fillOval(int x1,int y1,int w,int h);
    void fillRect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h);
    void drawTriangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2 , float x3, float y3);
    void fillTriangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2 , float x3, float y3);
    void fillRibbon(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2, int w);
    void drawRibbon(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2, int w);

    enum color{BLACK,BLUE,CYAN,DARK_GRAY,GRAY,GREEN,
        LIGHT_GRAY,MAGENTA,ORANGE,PINK,RED,WHITE,YELLOW,
        MAROON,PURPLE,LIME,OLIVE,NAVY,TEAL};
};

#endif
```

And here's the implementation, GameEngineV4.cpp:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------
// GameEngine Version 4.2 - Allegro, class Based, and 
// registered callbacks
// 4.1
// 4.2 Enhanced Audio
//-------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "GameEngineV4.h"
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>                //Our primitive header file
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_audio.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_acodec.h>
using namespace std;


//-------------------------------------------------------
// Definitions
//-------------------------------------------------------


#define WINDOW_WIDTH   800      // default size of game window
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT  600
#define T2SLEEP 20              // thread 2 default sleep time
#define T1SPEED 700000          // thread 1 default delay loops


//-------------------------------------------------------
// Global Variables
//-------------------------------------------------------

ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *beep1 = NULL;
ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *beep2 = NULL;

//-------------------------------------------------------
// Function pointers
//-------------------------------------------------------

void (*pGameMain) ()=NULL;
void (*pGameInit) ()=NULL;
void (*pGameQuit) ()=NULL;
void (*pGamePaint) ()=NULL;
void (*pGameKeyUp) (int)=NULL;
void (*pGameKeyDown) (int)=NULL;
void (*pGameLMouse) (int,int,int)=NULL;
void (*pGameRMouse) (int,int,int)=NULL;
void (*pGameMoveMouse) (int,int,int)=NULL;

enum KEYS{ UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT};

GameEngineV4::GameEngineV4()
{
    gSleep=T2SLEEP;
    gSpeed=T1SPEED;
    appRunning=false;
    for (int i=0;i<256;i++)
        keyTable[i]=0;
    default_pen=0;
    default_brush=0;
    default_font=0;
    default_BGColor=0;
    default_thickness=2.0;
    gdisplay = NULL;
}

int GameEngineV4::gameEngineMain(void)
{
    int width = WINDOW_WIDTH;
    int height = WINDOW_HEIGHT;

    bool done = false;
    bool redraw = true;

    int pos_x = width / 2;
    int pos_y = height / 2;

    int FPS = 60;

    bool keys[4] = {false, false, false, false};

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = NULL;

    if(!al_init())                                      //initialize Allegro
        return -1;

    display = al_create_display(width, height);         //create our display object

    if(!display)                                        //test display object
        return -1;

    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_install_keyboard();
    al_install_mouse();

    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();

    al_install_audio();
    al_init_acodec_addon();
    al_reserve_samples(10);

    beep1 = al_load_sample("beep1.ogg");
    beep2 = al_load_sample("beep2.ogg");


    initColorTable();
    initFontTable();
    initKeyTable();

    gameInit();
    //CreateThread(0,0,ThreadProc1,0,0,0);
    //CreateThread(0,0,ThreadProc2,0,0,0);
    event_queue = al_create_event_queue();
    timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / gameGetSpeed());

    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_mouse_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));


    al_start_timer(timer);
    while(!done)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
        al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);

        if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            keyPressed=true;
            pressedChar=keyTable[(int)ev.keyboard.keycode];
            gameKeyDown(keyTable[(int)ev.keyboard.keycode]);
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP)
        {
            keyPressed=true;
            pressedChar=keyTable[(int)ev.keyboard.keycode];
            gameKeyUp(keyTable[(int)ev.keyboard.keycode]);
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
        {
            gameMain();

            redraw = true;

        }else if (ev.type== ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_AXES)
        {   
            gameMoveMouse(ev.mouse.x,ev.mouse.y,1);

        }else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN)
        {
            if (ev.mouse.button & 1)
            {
                gameLMouse(ev.mouse.x,ev.mouse.y,1);
            }
            if (ev.mouse.button & 2)
            {
                gameRMouse(ev.mouse.x,ev.mouse.y,1);
            }
        }


        if(redraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(event_queue))
        {
            redraw = false;
            gamePaint();
            al_flip_display();
            al_clear_to_color(colortable[default_BGColor]);
        }
    }

    al_destroy_sample(beep1);
    al_destroy_sample(beep2);
    al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    al_destroy_display(display);                        //destroy our display object

    return 0;
}


/*
//-------------------------------------------------------
// Additional Game Threads
//-------------------------------------------------------

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc1(LPVOID lpParameter)
{   
gameMain1();
return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc2(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);

while(appRunning)
{
gameMain2();
GoPaint(NULL,NULL);
Sleep(gSleep);
}
return 0;
}
*/
//-------------------------------------------------------
// register callbacks and callbacks
//-------------------------------------------------------
void GameEngineV4:: registerGameMain(void (*fun)() )
{
    pGameMain = fun ;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameMain()
{
    if (pGameMain !=NULL) pGameMain();
}
void GameEngineV4:: registerGameInit(void (*fun)() )
{
    pGameInit = fun ;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameInit()
{
    if (pGameInit !=NULL) pGameInit();
}
void GameEngineV4:: registerGameQuit(void (*fun)() )
{
    pGameQuit = fun ;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameQuit()
{
    if (pGameQuit !=NULL) pGameQuit();
}
void GameEngineV4:: registerGamePaint(void (*fun)() )
{
    pGamePaint = fun ;
}
void GameEngineV4::gamePaint()
{
    if (pGamePaint !=NULL) pGamePaint();
}
void GameEngineV4:: registerGameKeyUp(void (*fun)(int) )
{
    pGameKeyUp = fun ;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameKeyUp(int x)
{
    if (pGameKeyUp !=NULL) pGameKeyUp(x);
}
void GameEngineV4:: registerGameKeyDown(void (*fun)(int) )
{
    pGameKeyDown = fun ;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameKeyDown(int x)
{
    if (pGameKeyDown !=NULL) pGameKeyDown(x);
}
void GameEngineV4:: registerGameLMouse(void (*fun)(int,int,int) )
{
    pGameLMouse = fun ;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameLMouse(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (pGameLMouse !=NULL) pGameLMouse(x, y, z);
}
void GameEngineV4:: registerGameRMouse(void (*fun)(int,int,int) )
{
    pGameRMouse = fun ;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameRMouse(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (pGameRMouse !=NULL) pGameRMouse(x, y, z);
}
void GameEngineV4:: registerGameMoveMouse(void (*fun)(int,int,int) )
{
    pGameMoveMouse = fun ;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameMoveMouse(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (pGameMoveMouse !=NULL) pGameMoveMouse(x, y, z);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------
// Pens and Brushes
//-------------------------------------------------------
void GameEngineV4::initColorTable()
{
    colortable[0]=al_map_rgb(0,0,0);            // black
    colortable[1]=al_map_rgb(0,0,255);          // blue
    colortable[2]=al_map_rgb(0,255,255);        // cyan /aqua
    colortable[3]=al_map_rgb(96,96,96);     // dark gray

    colortable[4]=al_map_rgb(160,160,160);      // gray
    colortable[5]=al_map_rgb(0,160,0);          // green
    colortable[6]=al_map_rgb(192,192,192);      // light gray /silver
    colortable[7]=al_map_rgb(255,0,255);        // magenta

    colortable[8]=al_map_rgb(255,165,0);        // orange
    colortable[9]=al_map_rgb(255,160,203);      // pink
    colortable[10]=al_map_rgb(255,0,0);     // red
    colortable[11]=al_map_rgb(255,255,255);     // white

    colortable[12]=al_map_rgb(255,255,0);       // yellow
    colortable[13]=al_map_rgb(160,0,0);     // maroon
    colortable[14]=al_map_rgb(160,0,160);       // purplE
    colortable[15]=al_map_rgb(0,255,0);     // lime

    colortable[16]=al_map_rgb(160,160,0);       // olive
    colortable[17]=al_map_rgb(0,0,160);     // navy
    colortable[18]=al_map_rgb(0,160,160);       // teal


}
void GameEngineV4::initFontTable()
{
    fonttable[0] = al_load_font("arial.ttf", 16, 1);
    fonttable[1] = al_load_font("arial.ttf", 32, 2);
    fonttable[2] = al_load_font("arial.ttf", 48, 2);
}

void GameEngineV4::initKeyTable()
{
    for (int i=0; i< 256;i++) 
        keyTable[i]=0; // zero
    keyTable[84]=0x26; // keyup
    keyTable[85]=0x28; // key down
    keyTable[82]=0x25; // left
    keyTable[83]=0x27; // right
    for (int i=0; i< 26;i++) 
        keyTable[i+1]=i+0x41; // a-z
    for (int i=0; i< 9;i++) 
        keyTable[i+27]=i+0x30; // 0-9
    for (int i=0; i< 9;i++) 
        keyTable[i+37]=i+0x60; // 0-9 key pad
    for (int i=0; i< 12;i++) 
        keyTable[i+47]=i+0x70; // F1-F12
    keyTable[59]=0x1b; // escape
    keyTable[61]=0x6d; // minus
    keyTable[63]=0x08; // backspace
    keyTable[64]=0x09; // tab
    keyTable[75]=0x20; // space
    keyTable[67]=0x0d; // return or enter

}



//-------------------------------------------------------
// Text Procssing
//-------------------------------------------------------

void GameEngineV4::text_out(char *txt,int x,int y,int clr)
{
    al_draw_text(fonttable[default_font], colortable[clr], x, y, 0, txt);
}

void GameEngineV4::text_out(char *txt,int x,int y)
{
    al_draw_text(fonttable[default_font], colortable[default_pen], x, y, 0, txt);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
//  Functions to Draw Lines and Shapes
//-------------------------------------------------------

void GameEngineV4::draw_line(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)
{
    al_draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, colortable[default_pen],default_thickness);
}
void GameEngineV4::draw_line(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int clr)
{
    al_draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, colortable[clr] ,default_thickness);
}
void GameEngineV4::draw_ellipse(int x1,int y1,int w,int h,int penClr,int brushClr)
{
    int w1=w/2;
    int h1=h/2;
    al_draw_ellipse(x1+w1, y1+h1, w1, h1, colortable[penClr], default_thickness); 
}
void GameEngineV4::draw_rect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h)
{
    al_draw_rectangle(x1,y1,x1+w,y1+h,colortable[default_pen],default_thickness);
}
void GameEngineV4::draw_rect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h,int penClr,int brushClr)
{
    al_draw_rectangle(x1,y1,x1+w,y1+h,colortable[penClr],default_thickness);
}
void GameEngineV4::draw_ellipse(int x1,int y1,int w,int h)
{
    int w1=w/2;
    int h1=h/2;
    al_draw_ellipse(x1, y1, w1, h1, colortable[default_pen], default_thickness); 
}
void GameEngineV4::fill_ellipse(int x1,int y1,int w,int h,int penClr,int brushClr)
{
    int w1=w/2;
    int h1=h/2;

    al_draw_filled_ellipse (x1+w1,y1+h1,w1,h1,colortable[penClr]);
}
void GameEngineV4::fill_ellipse(int x1,int y1,int w,int h)
{
    int w1=w/2;
    int h1=h/2;

    al_draw_filled_ellipse (x1+w1,y1+h1,w1,h1,colortable[default_brush]);

}
void GameEngineV4::fill_rect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h)
{
    al_draw_filled_rectangle(x1,y1,x1+w,y1+h,colortable[default_brush]);

}
void GameEngineV4::fill_rect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h,int penClr,int brushClr)
{
    al_draw_filled_rectangle(x1,y1,x1+w,y1+h,colortable[penClr]);
}

void GameEngineV4::color(int pen,int brush)
{
    default_pen=pen;
    default_brush=brush;
}
void GameEngineV4::pen_color(int pen)
{
    default_pen=pen;
}
void GameEngineV4::brush_color(int brush)
{
    default_brush=brush;
}
int GameEngineV4::gameLastkey()
{
    if(!keyPressed)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        keyPressed=false;   
        return pressedChar;
    }
}
void GameEngineV4::gameSetSpeed(int x)
{
    gSpeed=x;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameSetGameSpeed(int x)
{
    gSpeed=x;
}
void GameEngineV4::gameSetDisplayDelay(int x)
{
    gSleep=x;
}
int GameEngineV4::gameGetSpeed()
{
    return gSpeed;
}
int GameEngineV4::gameGetGameSpeed()
{
    return gSpeed;
}

// graphics interface
int GameEngineV4::initializePanel(int width, int height)
{
    if(!al_init())                                      //initialize Allegro
        return -1;
    gdisplay = al_create_display(width, height);            //create our display object

    if(!gdisplay)                                       //test display object
        return -1;

    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_install_keyboard();
    al_install_mouse();

    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();

    al_install_audio();
    al_init_acodec_addon();
    al_reserve_samples(100);

    initColorTable();
    initFontTable();
    initKeyTable();
    return 0;
}

void GameEngineV4::closePanel()
{
    al_destroy_display(gdisplay);                       //destroy our display object
    return;
}
void GameEngineV4::displayPanel()
{
    al_flip_display();
}
void GameEngineV4::setBackground(int color)
{
    default_BGColor =color;
    al_clear_to_color(colortable[default_BGColor]);
}

void GameEngineV4::setBackground(int r, int g, int b)
{
    colortable[30] =al_map_rgb(r,g,b);
    default_BGColor =30;
    al_clear_to_color(colortable[default_BGColor]);
}
void GameEngineV4::setThickness(double t)
{
    default_thickness=t;
}
void GameEngineV4::setPenColor(int pen)
{
    default_pen=pen;
}
void GameEngineV4::setColor(int clr)
{
    default_pen=clr;
    default_brush=clr;
}

void GameEngineV4::setColor(int r, int g, int b)
{
    colortable[31] =al_map_rgb(r,g,b);
    default_pen=31;
}

void GameEngineV4::setBrushColor(int brush)
{
    default_brush=brush;
}

void GameEngineV4::setBrushColor(int r, int g, int b)
{
    colortable[30] =al_map_rgb(r,g,b);
    default_brush=30;
}
void GameEngineV4::setFont(int font)
{
    default_font=font;
}
void GameEngineV4::setFontSize(int fontSize, int flag)
{
    fonttable[31] = al_load_font("arial.ttf", fontSize, flag);
    default_font=31;
}
void GameEngineV4::setFont(string family, int fontSize, int flag)
{
    fonttable[31] = al_load_font(family.c_str(), fontSize, flag);
    default_font=31;
}

void GameEngineV4::drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    al_draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, colortable[default_pen] ,default_thickness);   
}
void GameEngineV4::drawOval(int x1,int y1,int w,int h)
{
    int w1=w/2;
    int h1=h/2;
    al_draw_ellipse(x1+w1, y1+h1, w1, h1, colortable[default_pen], default_thickness); 
}
void GameEngineV4::drawRect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h)
{
    al_draw_rectangle(x1,y1,x1+w,y1+h,colortable[default_pen],default_thickness);
}
void GameEngineV4::drawString(char *txt,int x,int y)
{
    text_out(txt,x,y);
}
void GameEngineV4::drawString(string txt,int x,int y)
{
    al_draw_text(fonttable[default_font], colortable[default_pen], x, y, 0, txt.c_str());
}
void GameEngineV4::fillOval(int x1,int y1,int w,int h)
{
    int w1=w/2;
    int h1=h/2;
    al_draw_filled_ellipse (x1+w1,y1+h1,w1,h1,colortable[default_brush]);
}
void GameEngineV4::fillRect(int x1,int y1,int w,int h)
{
    al_draw_filled_rectangle(x1,y1,x1+w,y1+h,colortable[default_brush]);
}
void GameEngineV4::displayDelay(double d)
{
    al_rest(d);
}

void GameEngineV4::drawARC(int x1,int y1, int r, int w,int h,float st, float dt)
{
    int w1=w/2;
    int h1=h/2;
    float dt1=3.14 * (dt*-1)/180.0;
    float st1=3.14 * (st*-1)/180.0;
    al_draw_arc(x1+w1,y1+h1,r,st1,dt1,colortable[default_brush],default_thickness);

}

void GameEngineV4::playBeep1()
{
    al_play_sample(beep1, 1, 0, 1, ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE, 0);
}

void GameEngineV4::playBeep2()
{
    al_play_sample(beep2, 1, 0, 1 , ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE, 0);
}

void GameEngineV4::playBeep(float g, float s )
{
    al_play_sample(beep1, g, 0, s, ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE, 0);
}

void GameEngineV4::playWav(char filename[], float gain, float speed, float duration  )
{
    ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *soundeffect = al_load_sample(filename);
    al_play_sample(soundeffect,gain,0.0, speed, ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE, 0);
    al_rest(duration);
    al_destroy_sample(soundeffect);
}

void GameEngineV4::playWave(string filename, float gain, float speed, float duration  )
{
    ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *soundeffect = al_load_sample(filename.c_str());
    al_play_sample(soundeffect,gain,0.0, speed, ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE, 0);
    al_rest(duration);
    al_destroy_sample(soundeffect);
}

// audio interface
int GameEngineV4::initializeAudio(int samples)
{
    if(!al_init())                                      //initialize Allegro
        return -1;
    al_install_audio();
    al_init_acodec_addon();
    al_reserve_samples(samples);
    return 0;
}

void GameEngineV4::drawTriangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2 , float x3, float y3)
{
    al_draw_triangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,colortable[default_pen],default_thickness);
}

void GameEngineV4::fillTriangle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2 , float x3, float y3)
{
    al_draw_filled_triangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,colortable[default_brush]);
}
void GameEngineV4::fillRibbon(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2, int w)
{
    struct MyPoint
    {
        float x, y;
    };

    const size_t num_points1 = 2;

    MyPoint points1[] = 
    {

        {x1, y1},
        {x2, y2}

    };

    al_draw_ribbon((float*)points1, sizeof(MyPoint), colortable[default_brush], w, num_points1);

}
void GameEngineV4::drawRibbon(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2, int w)
{
    fillRibbon(x1,y1,x2,y2, w);
}
```

EDIT: ANSWERED. See top for more info.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing this 'simplification" of Allegro but I'm guessing you don't want to make copies of `GameEngineV4` when you pass it to `drawBackground`. I'm betting you should be passing by reference.

Comment: I updated the question with the header and implementation files for the simplification of Allegro. Thanks for the help! Passing by reference (Which I should have been doing in the first place) did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my drawBackground function, I am supposed to provide the starting point of the line and the ending point of the line. I provided the same point for both the start and end point. End result, nothing displayed.